# Projections: Ordering

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a unital C*-algebra $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

Consider projections:
$$P^2=P=P^*\quad P'^2=P'=P'^*$$

Order them by:
$$P\leq P':\iff\sigma(\Delta P)\geq0\quad(\Delta P:=P'-P)$$

> Then equivalently:
>   $$P\leq P'\iff P=PP'=P'P\iff\Delta P^2=\Delta P=\Delta P^*$$

How can I check this?

*(Operator algebraic proof?)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion $P\leq Q$ means $Q-P\geq0$. Then
$$
0\leq P(Q-P)P=PQP-P\leq P^2-P=P-P=0.
$$
So $P=PQP$. Now we can write this equality as $$0=P-PQP=P(I-Q)P=[(I-Q)P]^*[(I-Q)P],$$
so $(I-Q)P=0$, i.e. $P=QP$. Taking adjoints, $P=PQ$.

The converse also holds: if $P=PQ=QP $, then $$Q-P=Q^2-QPQ=Q (I-P)Q\geq0. $$

**Edit:** for the equivalence $Q-P\geq0$ iff $Q-P$ is a projection:

I think it is easier to show that $Q-P$ is a projection iff $P=PQ=QP$ (the latter being equivalent to $Q-P\geq0$ by the above).

If $Q-P$ is a projection, then $$Q-P=(Q-P)^2=Q+P-PQ-QP,$$ so $$\tag{1}2P=PQ+QP.$$ Multiplying by $I-P$ on the left, we get $(I-P)QP=0$, or $QP=PQP$. Taking adjoints, we obtain $QP=PQ$. Now $(1)$ is $2P=2PQ$, i.e. $P=PQ=QP$.

Conversely, if $P=QP=PQ$, then 
$$
(Q-P)^2=Q+P-PQ-QP=Q+P-2P=Q-P.
$$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think the second inequality must be corrected. For $A\leq B$ it does not follow $A+C\leq B+C$ but only $C^*AC\leq C^*BC$. So instead one could write: From $Q\leq1$ it follows $P(Q-1)P\leq P0P$ *(Of course the result is still right but the argument seems not so right.)* In any case: Thanks alot!!! :DD (+1)

Comment: By the way nice check!! :D _(I was hoping for conjugation and C*-property.)_

Comment: Of course it follows from $A\leq B$ that $A+C\leq B+C$! It's just $(B+C)-(A+C)=B-A$.  The argument you mention does not work because you cannot guarantee that $P(Q-I)P$ is positive.

Comment: Aaah right you're right!! Besides I think the other argument works to as you want to guarantee that it is not positive but negative that it is as $Q\leq1$.

Comment: The point is not showing that it is negative, but that it is zero. If you cannot squeeze from one side, the argument doesn't work.

Comment: Yes and that seems the right squeezing: Sloppy saying, exploiting $P\leq Q$ and $Q\leq I$ sandwich the middle part $(Q-P)\cong(Q-I)$. What do you think? Sorry if I mistook it!

Comment: By the way, does the converse hold true: For projections $P$ and $Q$ does $P=PQ=QP$ imply $P\leq Q$?

Comment: Yes, of course: $$Q-P=Q^2-QPQ=Q(I-P)Q\geq0.$$

Comment: Thanks alot for the nice check!!! :))

Comment: Can you add this to your answer, pleease?

Comment: Done. $\ {\ \ } $

Comment: Do you mind adding the second equivalence?

Comment: Like along the lines: $\Delta P\geq0\implies P=PP'=P'P\implies\Delta P^2=\Delta P=\Delta P^*\implies\Delta P\geq0$

Comment: The point is it would be preparation for another thread... Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: Done. ${\ \ \ }$

Comment: Great great thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If $Q \ge P$, then
\begin{align}
      \|Px\|^{2} & =\|QPx\|^{2}+\|(I-Q)Px\|^{2} \\
            & = (PQPx,x)+\|(I-Q)Px\|^{2} \\
            & \ge (PPPx,x)+\|(I-Q)Px\|^{2} \\
            & = \|Px\|^{2}+\|(I-Q)Px\|^{2} \\
         \implies & (I-Q)Px=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Oh but that is operator-theoretic..

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken:
It requires to know that $\langle\sigma(A)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$ for $A=A^*$. The usual knowledge though is only $\langle\sigma(A)\rangle\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$ for $A\in\mathcal{B}(E)$. But this is not enough in this case here. Or what do you think?

Comment: And every $C^{\star}$ algebra is ... .

Comment: Sure every C*-algebra is an operator algebra by Gelfand-Naimark. But still that is operator theoretic and I think it can be solved in an operator algebraic way. *(The result is purely operator algebraic and elementary enough.)*

Comment: Still the inequality is not clear: From $P\leq Q$ it follows $PPP\leq PQP$. But why then $\langle PPPx,x\rangle\leq\langle PQPx,x\rangle$?

Comment: @Freeze_S : For $A=A^{\star}$, you have $(Ax,x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ iff $A \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes and how do you prove that? The 'if' part requires continuous calculus, or? And the representation requires Gelfand-Naimark. *(Both nontrivial results!)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : For $A=A^{\star}$, you can show that $\inf_{\|x\|=1}(Ax,x)$ is always in the spectrum of $A$ and $\sup_{\|x\|=1}(Ax,x)$ is in the spectrum (as you would expect by symmetry.) That's basically just Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @Freeze_S : By the way, the property I just gave you will give you the spectral theorem for bounded selfadjoint operators, knowing only that all bounded linear functionals on $C[a,b]$ are Riemann-Stieltjes integrals with respect to functions of bounded variation (or if it it makes you happy, integrals with respect to complex Borel measures on $[a,b]$.) Can you see why?