# Projections: Orthogonality

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Given a unital C*-algebra $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

Consider projections:
$$P^2=P=P^*\quad P'^2=P'=P'^*$$

Order them by:
$$P\perp P':\iff\sigma(\Sigma P)\leq1\quad(\Sigma P:=P+P')$$

> Then equivalently:
>   $$P\perp P'\iff 0=PP'=P'P\iff\Sigma P^2=\Sigma P=\Sigma P^*$$

How can I check this?

*(Operator algebraic proof?)*

Comment: Could you please explain what $P\perp P'\geq 0$ means? (I suppose you mean $\sum P:= P+P'$ above as well.)

Comment: @Bryder: Oh that was a typo. Thanks!! *(Corrected.)*

Comment: Also, there is no ordering, really - what you really do is define orthogonality. :)

Comment: @Bryder: Yes no ordering because not transitive due to sum instead of difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm assuming that by $\sigma(\Sigma P)\leq1$ you mean that $\|\Sigma P\|\leq1$.*

1. Suppose that $\|P+Q\|\leq1$. So $0\leq P+Q\leq 1$. Then $(P+Q)^2\leq P+Q$ (just conjugate with $(P+Q)^{1/2}$). That is, 
   $$
   P+Q+QP+PQ\leq P+Q,
   $$
   or $QP+PQ\leq0$. If we conjugate this inequality with $Q$, we get $QPQ+QPQ\leq0$. But $QPQ\geq0$, so $QPQ=0$. Then 
   $$
   0=QPQ=(PQ)^*PQ,
   $$
   and then $PQ=0$. By taking adjoints, $QP=0$.

$$
\ 
$$

2. If $PQ=0$, it follows by taking adjoints that $QP=0$. And
   $$
   (P+Q)^2=P^2+Q^2+QP+PQ=P+Q.
   $$

$$
\ 
$$

3. If $(P+Q)^2=P+Q$, then by the C$^*$-identity
   $$
   \|P+Q\|^2=\|(P+Q)^2\|=\|P+Q\|,
   $$
   so either $\|P+Q\|=0$ (which by positivity would force $P=Q=0$) or $\|P+Q\|=1$.

Comment: Woohoo nice :D Thanks alot!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Let's enumerate the conditions:
(1) $P\perp P'$;
(2) $0=PP'=P'P$;
(3) $\Sigma P$ is a projection.

We can assume that $A\subset B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$ (this basically follows from the GNS construction); also, remember that for positive operators $T\in B(H)$ we have $\langle T\xi,\xi\rangle\geq 0$ for all $\xi\in H$.

For (1)$\Rightarrow$(2), assume that $\xi\in P(H)$ and note that $\langle (P+P')\xi,\xi\rangle\leq\langle\xi,\xi\rangle=\|\xi\|^2$ by assumption (since $0\leq P+P'\leq 1$). Since $\langle P\xi,\xi\rangle=\|\xi\|^2$, we have $ \|P'\xi\|^2=\langle P'\xi,\xi\rangle=0$, so that $\xi=(1-P')\xi+P'\xi=(1-P')\xi$. Thus for all $\eta\in H$, note that $P\eta\in P(H)$, so that we have $P\eta=(1-P')P\eta$ by what we found above. This means that $P'P\eta=0$ for all $\eta\in H$, so $P'P=0$. Taking the adjoint yields (2). (3) follows from (2) by just computing, and any projection $Q\in A$ satisfies $0\leq Q\leq 1$, so if (3) holds, then $\sigma(\Sigma P)\subset[0,1]$ immediately.

Comment: Nice but that proof is operator-theoretic.. Do you know an operator-algebraic proof? More seriously it requires to know that  spectrum and numerical range agree $\langle\sigma(N)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}$ for normals $N^*N=NN^*$ *(That is far from trivial!!)* or for selfadjoints $A=A^*$ *(Still nontrivial!)*.

Comment: I always define positive operators as those of the form $a^*a$, so that may explain part of why I did as I did above. I haven't encountered a solution that doesn't in some way involve the GNS construction. :)

Comment: Ok maybe I'll figure out one. *(See also [Ordering](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1351252/79762).)*

Comment: You may not be able to get around the spectral radius formula if you decide to go full-on operator-algebraic, anyway - for instance, if we are to show that $P+Q\geq 0$ for $P,Q\geq 0$ then I don't know of a proof that avoids that formula.

Comment: @Bryder: it is not hard to do it without mention of the spectral radius by using a little functional calculus (namely, the existence of square roots). Then you can show that $X\geq0$ if and only if $\|\lambda-X\|\leq\lambda$ for all $\lambda\geq\|X\|$, and with this characterization it is straighforward to show that the sum of positives is positive.

Comment: Ah! Just to be clear - how would you then define $X\geq 0$? By means of the spectrum, or $X=Y^*Y$ for some $Y$?